# KornShell Script - Parent Process not Completing when Child is Interrupted (TRAP INT)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, aix

I have the following 2 scripts

**Parent.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
echo "In Parent : Before"
Child.sh
echo "In Parent : After"
read
```

**Child.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
function quit_handler
{
        echo "Quit on Child"
        stty $origtermconfig
        exit
}
origtermconfig="$(stty -g)"
trap quit_handler INT
while true
do
        echo "Child Says Hi"
        echo "Child PID is" $PID
        echo "Parent PID is " $PPID
        sleep 2
done
```

**Below is a session transcript**

```
u0012734@l273pp039_pub[/home/u0012734] > Parent.sh
In Parent : Before
Child Says Hi
Child PID is 16618
Parent PID is  18640
Child Says Hi
Child PID is 16618
Parent PID is  18640
Child Says Hi
Child PID is 16618
Parent PID is  18640    <----- I pressed CTRL-C Here
Quit on Child
u0012734@l273pp039_pub[/home/u0012734] >
```

I was expecting the parent script to continue execution of the third and fourth line of Parent.sh but that did not happen. What could be the issue? Please guide.

---

The below answer helped. I am also posting a link that has some good details related to [SIGINTs and handling it well](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or whatever character is configured to be the `INTR` character), `SIGINT` is sent to **all** processes in the foreground process group.  This includes the parent process in your example.  Your parent isn't configured to trap on `SIGINT` so it terminates.

Source:  [POSIX.1-2008 XBD section 11.1.9](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09)

Comment: Thanks @Richard Hansen . . . That helps a lot. If i add a trap in parent for INTR then it catches that just fine. This was a big help. Also, is there a way to override this behaviour? That the CHILD Process alone handles the SIGNAL without it propagating to parent?

Comment: @Guddu: It's best to ask that in a new question over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/  :-)

Comment: Thanks Richard I have created a post at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80975/preventing-propagation-of-sigint-to-parent-process